# Cayley's Matrix Notation

Tags: math-mode

Cayley used the following notation in his original paper 
*A Memoir on the Theory of Matrices* [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/108649.pdf)

[image]

My attempt to reproduce the notation is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{2.5}{\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{$$
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}, \mathrm{Z}){=}\lower10pt\hbox{$\begin{array}{r@{}c@{,\mkern10mu}c @{,\mkern10mu}c@{,\mkern10mu}c l}
  (   &a   &b   & c & )\\
 \lvert& a'  &b' & c' &\rvert\\
 \lvert& a'' & b'' & c'' & \rvert\\
\end{array}$}\mkern-6mu(x,y,z),
$$}}
\end{document}
```

As you will observe the delimiters need to be improved. Any suggestions?

Comment: is it just my eyes or am I right in thinking that on its own the () are symmetric pair  but the overlapping  )( symbol is using thinner more rounded )( to get more of an overlap so not using the matching parens for the outer borders of the matrices....

Comment: more `$(1,2,3\between 4,5,6)$` than `$(1,2,3)\!( 4,5,6)$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No it is the same thickness. There is a link to the Royal Society paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/108649.pdf

Comment: Yes that is the link I used, I see egreg also used `\between` see [this image copied from that pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e07m5.png), the overlapping brackets are not the same shape as the non-overlapping ones

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see what you mean, `\between` is a better choice.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I love old manuscripts. I didn't know the Cayley's matrix notation and I'll keep your question among my favorites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My proposal:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`Z}


\newsavebox{\cayleybox}
\newlength{\cayleyheight}
\newenvironment{cayleymatrix}[1]
 {\begin{lrbox}{\cayleybox}
  $\begin{array}{@{\enspace}l*{\numexpr#1-1}{@{{,}\enspace}l}@{\enspace}}}
 {\end{array}$\end{lrbox}%
  \setlength{\cayleyheight}{\dimexpr\ht\cayleybox+\dp\cayleybox}%
  \kern-0.8pt
  \vtop to \cayleyheight{\hbox{\vphantom{$\between$}}\leaders\vrule\vfill}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\ht\cayleybox}{\usebox\cayleybox}%
  \vtop to \cayleyheight{\hbox{\vphantom{$\between$}}\leaders\vrule\vfill}%
  \kern-0.8pt
 }
\newcommand{\by}{\kern-0.4pt{\between}\kern-0.4pt}

\thinmuskip=6mu
\medmuskip=0mu
\thickmuskip=0mu

\begin{document}

\[ % page 17
(X,Y,Z)=
(\begin{cayleymatrix}{3}
a   & b   & c \\
a'  & b'  & c' \\
a'' & b'' & c''
\end{cayleymatrix}
\by x,y,z)
\]

\[ % page 32
(\begin{cayleymatrix}{2} a & c \\ b & d \end{cayleymatrix} \by
\begin{cayleymatrix}{2} a & b \\ c & d \end{cayleymatrix} \by
\begin{cayleymatrix}{2} a & c \\ b & d \end{cayleymatrix} \by
\begin{cayleymatrix}{2} a & b \\ c & d \end{cayleymatrix} )
=
\bigl(
  (\begin{cayleymatrix}{2} a & c \\ b & d \end{cayleymatrix}\by
  \begin{cayleymatrix}{2} a & b \\ c & d \end{cayleymatrix})
\bigr)^2
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love your pictures :-) Congratulations on all the answers. The question is among my favorites.

Answer (score 6):

A Ti*k*Z proposal. Similarly to [Andrew's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487654/121799) you can focus on typing the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531/121799
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{CM}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\CayleyMatrix}[2][]{\stepcounter{CM}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.base),inner sep=2pt,#1]
  \matrix[matrix of math nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] (mat-\number\value{CM})
 { #2
  };
 \ifnodedefined{mat-\number\value{CM}-2-1}{%
 \draw[semithick] (mat-\number\value{CM}.south west) -- (mat-\number\value{CM}.south west|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.south) to[out=135,in=-135]
 (mat-\number\value{CM}.south west|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.north)
 (mat-\number\value{CM}.south east) -- (mat-\number\value{CM}.south east|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.south) to[out=45,in=-45]
 (mat-\number\value{CM}.south east|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.north) ;}{
 \draw[semithick] (mat-\number\value{CM}.south west|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.south) to[out=135,in=-135]
 (mat-\number\value{CM}.south west|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.north)
 (mat-\number\value{CM}.south east|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.south) to[out=45,in=-45]
 (mat-\number\value{CM}.south east|-mat-\number\value{CM}-1-1.north) ;
 }
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\[\CayleyMatrix{
X   \&Y   \& Z \\
}=\CayleyMatrix{
a   \&b   \& c \\
  a'  \&b' \& c' \\
  a'' \& b'' \& c'' \\
}\!\!\CayleyMatrix{
x   \&y   \& z \\
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Extending Bernard's idea slightly:

[image]

...but not quite up to the standards of egreg's nice solution:)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{cayley}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\stepcounter{cayley}%
\ifnum\value{cayley}=1\raisebox{-0.4ex}{(}\kern0.5ex\else\vline\fi}c@{}}
  \newcolumntype{R}{@{}c<{\space\ifnum\value{cayley}=1\kern0.5ex\raisebox{-0.4ex}{)}\else\vline\fi}}
\newenvironment{cayley}[1][3]{\setcounter{cayley}{0}\array{L*{#1}{c}R}}{\endarray}

\begin{document}

  \[
     \begin{cayley}
       &a  & b  & c  &\\
       &a' & b' & c' &\\
       &a''& b''& c''&\\
     \end{cayley}
     \qquad
     \begin{cayley}[4]
       &a  & b  & c  & d  &\\
       &a' & b' & c' & d' &\\
       &a''& b''& c''& d''&\\
     \end{cayley}
  \]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approximation, with basic commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \[ \begin{array}{c@{}ccc@{}c}
  (\mkern 4.2mu{} & a &b & c &\mkern 4.2mu)\\[-0.31ex]
   \vline & a' &b' & c' & \vline \\
   \vline & a'' &b'' & c''& \vline
\end{array} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]